# Is there a utility to generate a Com Class Wrapper from a non com .NET DLL?

Tags: com, wrapper

I have a 3rd party DLL that needs to be called as COM.  It is not COM, but it is a .NET DLL.  Are there any utilities that will auto generate a CCW for it?  Rather than making one by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio includes a program called "tlbexp", the Type Library exporter. This takes a .NET assembly and generates a COM type library out of it, which you can then import into a COM-based development tool like VB6.  You can also use the "regasm" tool on your assembly, which will export a type library and automatically register it on the machine.

All of this assumes that the third-party .NET DLL was written with COM in mind; the types need to be COM-visible for the exporter to pick them up. Also, unless the assembly contains the interop attributes to control the typelib generation, you're gonna get some pretty  rough-looking COM types (and really long ProgIds), but they should still work :)

Comment: That is the problem, it is not COM visible. But by the sounds of it there will just be a messy tbl.

Comment: If the .NET assembly doesn't have any COM-visible interfaces you're just going to have to write your own COM-visible wrappers around them (essentially pass-through calls) and generate a CCW from that. On the plus side, you can apply the proper interop attributes to make the typelib way less ugly (ClassInterfaceAttribute and ProgIdAttribute in particular).